# Javascript XML parsing of NOAA weather data - problems extracting data from child nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'd love some help with Javascript code I'm writing to extract weather data from NOAA xml files (downloaded from here: http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXML.htm ). For now I've just pasted in the relevant part of the XML as a string:

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML("<data>\
<weather time-layout=\"k-p3h-n40-2\">\
<name>Weather Type, Coverage, and Intensity</name>\
<weather-conditions/>\
<weather-conditions/>\
<weather-conditions/>\
<weather-conditions>\
<value coverage=\"areas\" intensity=\"none\" weather-type=\"sun\" qualifier=\"none\">\
<visibility xsi:nil=\"true\"/>\
</value>\
</weather-conditions>\
<weather-conditions>\
<value coverage=\"areas\" intensity=\"none\" weather-type=\"rain\" qualifier=\"none\">\
<visibility xsi:nil=\"true\"/>\
</value>\
</weather-conditions>\
<weather-conditions>\
<value coverage=\"areas\" intensity=\"none\" weather-type=\"fog\" qualifier=\"none\">\
<visibility xsi:nil=\"true\"/>\
</value>\
</weather-conditions>\
</data>")
```

I'm trying to extract all the  'weather-type' attributes using the following code:

```
var count = 0
var test_weather = new Array()
$(xmlDoc).find('weather').each(function(){
  $(this).find('weather-conditions').each(function(){
    $(this).find('value').each(function(){
      test_weather[count] = $(this).attr('weather-type')
      count=count+1
    })
  })
})
```

But this only finds the first weather type value, and I can't work out why! Any suggestions for what I'm doing wrong, or suggestions for how to improve my code, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: xmxl looks strange with all those nested `<weather-conditions>` is tht structure accurate?

Comment: @charlietfl: Yeah that's directly copied from the xml I downloaded. Not sure why it gives me all those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML is invalid. You can't use a namespace without declaring it.

As a result, jQuery isn't parsing anything past the first `xsi:nil` attribute (which is why you're only finding the first weather type value). You were also missing the closing `</weather>` tag.

If you declare a namespace, it should work as expected.

In this case:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

Which would translate to:

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML("<dwml xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" version=\"1.0\">\
  <data>\
    <!-- ... -->
  </data>\
</dwml>");
```

---

> Any suggestions for what I'm doing wrong, or suggestions for how to improve my code

You can improve your code by removing the nested `.each()` methods. You can simplify everything and use the [`.map()` method](http://api.jquery.com/map/) in order to map the `weather-type` attributes to the `test_weather` array:

[**Working Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/5oxh8na5/)

```
var test_weather = $('weather weather-conditions value', xmlDoc).map(function () {
  return $(this).attr('weather-type');
}).get();
```

Snippet with working code:

```js
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML("<dwml xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" version=\"1.0\">\
<data>\
<weather time-layout=\"k-p3h-n40-2\">\
<name>Weather Type, Coverage, and Intensity</name>\
<weather-conditions/>\
<weather-conditions/>\
<weather-conditions/>\
<weather-conditions>\
<value coverage=\"areas\" intensity=\"none\" weather-type=\"sun\" qualifier=\"none\">\
<visibility xsi:nil=\"true\"/>\
</value>\
</weather-conditions>\
<weather-conditions>\
<value coverage=\"areas\" intensity=\"none\" weather-type=\"rain\" qualifier=\"none\">\
<visibility xsi:nil=\"true\"/>\
</value>\
</weather-conditions>\
<weather-conditions>\
<value coverage=\"areas\" intensity=\"none\" weather-type=\"fog\" qualifier=\"none\">\
<visibility xsi:nil=\"true\"/>\
</value>\
</weather-conditions>\
</weather>\
</data>\
</dwml>");
var test_weather = $('weather weather-conditions value', xmlDoc).map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('weather-type');
}).get();

console.log(test_weather);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much, that's super helpful!